# How to display a tick box image in same line beside the textbox in password field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, .net

I have the below code that displays password textbox. When user enters password, it automatically displays status saying weak or strong etc and once its strong, it also adds a middle line with a small tick image in green color.

Problem is, I want this tick image to be on the right side of textbox and not on a new line.

Any help please?

```
var res = "";
res += "<input type='pwd' class='details_create' name='" + pwd + "' id='" + this.pwdid + "'>";    
res += "<span class='verify' id='pwdTickImage' style='display: none;margin-left: 300px;color:green;'></span>";
res += "<input type='text' class='details' name='" + this.pwdtxtfield + "' id='" + this.pwdtxtfieldid + "' style='display: none;'>";
```

Comment: unlucky, any help please?

Comment: include your details_create CSS

Comment: @Aizen: What you mean? Do you know the answer?

Comment: @unlucky, chetta, endho? reply

Comment: It is hard to tell. As we don't know what you're doing with the details_create css. We don't even know if it is taking the whole Div column or not making your <span> with a class "verify" there is no way of telling.

Comment: @Unlucky, why are you so unlucky? lol.

Comment: @Aizen: Fixed it mate, its quite simple, just add position as relative and put margins.